# event handling in wxpython

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

In wxpython, is it better to handle events by creating a separate function for each event handler (say a separate function for every single button click) or to create one large button_handler, and then determine the button clicked from there?

Basically, I am wondering if it is more resource intensive to have many different events being watched for each separate thing, or just one big event that will figure out which one was clicked when it was fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have three buttons that do radically different things, then I want different event handlers for them because I find that easier to debug. If they're all print buttons with slightly different formatting options applied, then I'll hook them all up to the same handler and use event.GetEventObject() to figure out which one called. The few times I've had multiple events handled by the same handler was when I had a toolbar button and a menu item both call the same thing. It has more to do with program flow and ease of debugging and that just comes with practice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it.  The resources required for either scheme will be trivial, especially in  a python script.  Focus on designing your code in the way that makes it easiest to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Resource intensity is not your issue here, but you would definitely want to use one big event loop for this. Due to the Global Interpreter Lock, many event handlers in python have annoying ways of dealing the event queue, and in some event handlers it may even be impossible to check the event without removing it from the stack (VPython for example), and so in these cases you may well run into strange and hard to track errors if you use multiple checks within your code. If you use one large event this won't happen, or if it does, will be much easier to track down.

Ravenspoint is correct in that the resource intensity of either approach is trivial, and based on resource intensity alone you shouldn't worry about it, but a single event loop is significantly easier to maintain.